# Is it possible to use ShellAndWait with MS Word VBA?

Tags: shell, vba, ms-word

I get the type not defined error for XlEnableCancelKey when trying to use [ShellAndWait](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ShellAndWait.aspx) with MS Word VBA. The Xl part of XlEnableCancelKey looks like it maybe an MS Excel type.

Also asked on [MSDN VBA Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/isvvba/thread/88614410-d9d1-4fb5-ba62-453e4c45420a).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Yes

In the VBA project, add a reference to the Microsoft Excel 12.0 Object Library.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`WdEnableCancelKey`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb209700%28v=office.12%29.aspx) instead of `XlEnableCancelKey`.
The reason being, for word a different enum type is defined which is used for `Application.EnableCancelKey`.

EDIT: Having looked at the link, I saw this line.
`Application.EnableCancelKey = xlErrorHandler`

Effectively, the code is wanting to use an enum value for `EnableCancelKey`.
Hence, you can use [`WdEnableCancelKey`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb209700%28v=office.12%29.aspx) in place of `XlErrorHandler`.

Comment: @shahkalpesh, thanks! That worked. But now I have another undefined variable xlErrorHandler, and replacing that with wdErrorHandler does not do the trick.

Comment: @Geoffrey: See the updated answer. Accept this answer, if it does what you are looking for. Thanks!!

Comment: After looking at MSDN library, I see that xlErrorHandler is one of the enumerated values of XlEnableCancelKey. There does not seem to be an enumerated value of WdEnableCancelkey equivalent to xlErrorHandler. This then seems to mean that ShellAndWait is not really useful for MS Word at the moment.

Comment: @Geoffrey: Yes, 'XlEnableCancelKey` enum has 3 values (`xlDisabled`, `xlErrorHandler`, `xlInterrupt`) that can be assigned. Whereas, `wdEnableCancelKey` has 2 values (`wdCancelDisabled`, `wdCancelInterrupt`). However, you can set the `EnableCancelKey` to `wdCancelDisabled` before calling `ShellAndWait` and set the `EnableCancelKey` to `wdCancelInterrupt`. In such a scenario, it won't break in the code while the shell operation is running, methinks.

Comment: @shahkalpesh, in the VBA project, I just added a reference to the Microsoft Excel 12.0 Object Library and it was not necessary to change the original ShellAndWait code anymore. See my answer.

Comment: @Geoffrey: It is not advisable to use an enum of Excel object library inside Word VBA.

Comment: @shahkalpesh Can you say why it's not advisable?

Comment: @Fuhrmanator: Think of it as an enum defined in Excel object library, which is the only thing you would want to refer to but nothing else. Adding a reference to Excel Object library and using classes/enums from it while within word VBA will load Excel object library in memory, which I don't think should be done.